# Filling between two list plots to reperesent a confidence band

Tags: plotting, filling

I've generated some confidence intervals for a Q-Q plot in the form of a list plot. However I am having some problems filing between the region. First of all here is the code to generate the intervals:

```
n = 64;
X = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], n];
\[Mu] = Mean[X];
\[Sigma] = StandardDeviation[X];
\[Alpha] = 0.05;
k = Sqrt[Log[2/\[Alpha]]/(2 n)];

neg = SortBy[Table[{x, InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]], 1/Length[X] Length[Select[X, # <= x &]] - k]}, {x, X}], #[[2]] &];
pos = SortBy[Table[{x, InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]], 1/Length[X] Length[Select[X, # <= x &]] + k]}, {x, X}], #[[2]] &];

Show[
        {
            QuantilePlot[X, NormalDistribution[Mean[X], StandardDeviation[X]],ImageSize->Automatic->200, LabelStyle->12, PlotStyle->Red],
            ListLinePlot[{neg, pos}, Filling->{{1->{2}}}, FillingStyle->Directive[{Gray,Opacity[0.1]}]]
    
        }, PlotRange->{{-2,2 }, {-2, 2}}
    ]
```

[image]

As you can see the filling works as instructed, but it's not what I want. I'd like to fill the region of the plot area which is bounded by the confidence band. I thought I might be able to make a hack by adding an additional diagonal plot which I then hide to reference where the filling occurs. This almost works:

```
Show[
        {
            QuantilePlot[X, NormalDistribution[Mean[X], StandardDeviation[X]],ImageSize->Automatic->200, LabelStyle->12, PlotStyle->Red],
            ListLinePlot[{neg, pos, Table[{x, x}, {x, -3, 3}]},  Filling->{{1->{3}}, {2->{3}}}, FillingStyle->Directive[{Gray,Opacity[0.1]}]]
        }, PlotRange->{{-2,2 }, {-2, 2}}
    ]
```

This gets me closer,but I have these regions missing in the corners:

[image]

Comment: Look at your data. E.g. data in "pos" has only points from x==-2 up to x==1.Therefore, you can not have  filling to points that do not exists. Similar thing with "neg"

Comment: The problem is that `1/Length[X] Length[Select[X, # <= x &]] - k`] and `1/Length[X] Length[Select[X, # <= x &]] - k]` can give values less than 0 and greater than 1, respectively. And such values don't work with `InverseCDF` (which need to be between 0 and 1). A crude fix is to use something like `Min[0.999999, Max[0.000001, 1/Length[X] Length[Select[X, # <= x &]] - k]]]` and `Min[0.999999, Max[0.000001, 1/Length[X] Length[Select[X, # <= x &]] + k]]]`. Zero and one can't be used because that gets you −∞ and +∞

Comment: This turned out to be the easiest fix, thanks again @JimB. I'm accepting Jean-Pierre's answer as I found it useful for other things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reverse cheating:

```
Show[{QuantilePlot[X, 
   NormalDistribution[Mean[X], StandardDeviation[X]], 
   ImageSize -> Automatic -> 200, LabelStyle -> 12, PlotStyle -> Red],
   Graphics[{Opacity[0.1], Gray, Rectangle[{-2, -2}, {2, 2}]}], 
  ListLinePlot[{neg, pos}, Filling -> {1 -> -2, 2 -> 2},
   FillingStyle -> White]}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

(1) Remove pairs with non-numeric elements from `neg` and `pos`, (2) `Prepend` (`Append`) `neg`  (`pos`) with a point so that both series have the same horizontal and vertical ranges:

```
newpoints = Transpose @ CoordinateBounds[Join @@ (Cases[{__Real}] /@ {neg, pos})];

negpos = MapThread[# @ #2 &] @ 
 {{Prepend[First @ newpoints], Append[Last @ newpoints]}, Cases[{__Real}] /@ {neg, pos}}


Show[{QuantilePlot[X, NormalDistribution[Mean[X], StandardDeviation[X]], 
   ImageSize -> Automatic -> 200, LabelStyle -> 12, PlotStyle -> Red],
   ListLinePlot[negpos, Filling -> {{1 -> {2}}}, 
   FillingStyle -> Directive[{Gray, Opacity[0.1]}]]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]